# SQL sum between dates

Tags: sql, date, grouping, intersect

I need to sum values in intersect of range dates.

sample of source data

| person | item | start_date | end_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | apple | 08.03.2018 | 29.03.2018 | 3 |
| a | apple | 01.01.2019 | 08.08.2021 | 2 |
| a | apple | 01.01.2019 | 09.10.2021 | 5 |
| a | pen | 10.10.2021 | 30.10.2021 | 2 |
| a | cup | 08.03.2018 | 20.03.2018 | 8 |
| a | cup | 15.03.2018 | 20.03.2019 | 2 |
| b | pen | 10.10.2021 | 30.10.2021 | 2 |
| b | pen | 10.10.2021 | 30.10.2021 | 6 |
| b | orange | 10.11.2021 | 10.11.2022 | 3 |
| b | orange | 20.11.2021 | 20.12.2021 | 2 |

expected result

| person | item | start_date | end_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | apple | 08.03.2018 | 29.03.2018 | 3 |
| a | apple | 01.01.2019 | 08.08.2021 | 7 |
| a | apple | 09.08.2021 | 09.10.2021 | 5 |
| a | pen | 10.10.2021 | 30.10.2021 | 2 |
| a | cup | 08.03.2018 | 14.03.2018 | 8 |
| a | cup | 15.03.2018 | 20.03.2018 | 10 |
| a | cup | 21.03.2018 | 20.03.2019 | 2 |
| b | pen | 10.10.2021 | 30.10.2021 | 8 |
| b | orange | 10.11.2021 | 19.11.2021 | 3 |
| b | orange | 20.11.2021 | 20.12.2021 | 5 |
| b | orange | 21.12.2021 | 10.11.2022 | 3 |

I use something code like this, but it is to simple, and results are not good

```
  select
  person
  ,item
  ,Min([start_date]) as [start_date]
  ,Max([end_date]) as [end_date]
  ,Sum([value]) as [value]
  FROM table
  Group by   person, item
```

I tried to use LAG() function, but i'm lost

Comment: what database is it ? mysql, postgresql, oracle ?

Comment: It is azure synapse sql dedicated pool

Comment: can you give the exact rule that defines what you want the value column to contain in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no access to Synapse , but assuming it's compatibile with SQL server...

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7504b967e98278e7d5c6a4c43748c5b8)

Internal query build data ranges, creating additional dates for overlapping periods if needed. Main query just sum values.

```sql
select person, item, range_from, range_to, 
       (select sum(value) from test 
            where person = r.person 
              and item = r.item 
              and range_from between start_date and end_date) value
from ( 
  select 
     be, 
     person, 
     item, 
     date range_from, 
     lead(date,1) over(partition by person, item order by date,be) range_to 
  from (      
     select 1 be, person, item, start_date date from test
     union 
     select 2, person, item, end_date from test
     union  
     select 2, person, item, dateadd(day,-1,start_date) from test a
       where exists (select * from test where a.person = person and a.item = item and a.start_date > start_date and a.start_date < end_date)
     union 
     select 1, person, item, dateadd(day,1,end_date) from test b
       where exists (select * from test where b.person = person and b.item = item and b.end_date > start_date and b.end_date < end_date)
  ) k 
) r where r.be = 1 order by r.person, r.item, r.range_from
```

column `be` contains:

- 1 - for period start
- 2 - for period end